# "Reassign to" or "reassign in"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

I'm not a native English speaker and I'm always confused with the usage of prepositions.

> - Vehicle’s ownership is reassigned **to** the name of the loan officer
> - Vehicle’s ownership is reassigned **in** the name of the loan officer

Comment: I would avoid any loan officer who tries to get you to reassign vehicle ownership to their name.

Comment: The ownership is reassigned _to_ the lender.  That's who holds the claim (lien) on the car. The vehicle Title is re-issued _in_ the name of the lender.

Comment: Ownership is *never* transferred when taking out a loan (only when defaulting on a loan)  A lien is placed on the property *owned by the borrower*, so that the lender has recourse if the borrower fails to make the required payments.

Comment: @LuvsanorjBatbayar - Of all the mistakes you might make, prepositions are the least serious.  Yes, they are confusing.  But you're not the only one.  People will be more tolerant of a slightly off preposition than of a badly conjugated verb, for example.

Answer (score 1):

"Assign" has the meaning of a transfer, here of ownership.  This is a from-to action between persons, so the English idiom prefers "to."  Since ownership changes hands (a metaphorical usage meaning people), it would be better to keep the exchange between people, not names:

> The vehicle's ownership is reassigned **to** the loan officer.

The document that signifies ownership is called the vehicle's title, and this piece of paper records the name of the owner.  For this proof of ownership, the English idiom uses "in":

> The vehicle is retitled **in** the name of the loan officer.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, but they mean different things.

> The vehicle’s ownership is reassigned to the name of the loan officer.

The *to* version means that the loan officer gains ownership of the vehicle.

> The vehicle’s ownership is reassigned in the name of the loan officer.

The *in* version means that the loan officer authorised the reassignment (to an unnamed person), or alternatively, that the loan officer's authority was invoked to reassign the vehicle (again, to an unnamed person).

> **In the name of**
>   1. By the authority of: *Open up in the name of the law!* - [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+name+of)